# Delete a collection if empty Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to delete the collection if there are no docs in it with flutter?
There are some cases when the 'visited' collection could be empty and in this case I don't need it anymore...

[image]

Comment: You cannot have empty collections. Are you deleting all the docs while the console is open? If yes, try refreshing it.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @Dharmaraj 

Answer (score 2):

There are no empty collections in Firestore. If there is no document in a collection it won't show up in the console. It seems you deleted the documents while the console was open and that's why you can see an empty collection.
I just checked that and confirmed it. Refreshing the console should remove it from the list.

[image]